# How to detect when socket connection is lost?

Tags: perl, sockets, networking, io

I have a script (I don't have the code example here at the moment but I used IO::Async) which connects to socket on a remote server and listens. Client usually just listens for new data.

Problem is that the client is not able to detect if network problems occur and the socket connection is gone.
I used IO::Async and I also tried it with IO::Socket. Handle is always "connected" after the initial connection is established.

If the network connection is established again the socket connection is naturally still lost because the script has no idea that it should reconnect.

I was thinking to create some kind of "keepAlive" which "pings" (syswrite) the socket every X seconds (if nothing new came through socket) to check whether the connection is still there.

Is this the correct way to do it or is there maybe an another more creative or cleaner solution?

Comment: I think the 'heartbeat' procedure you're talking about is the only known solution to this problem. It's quite clean and creative, I assure you. )

Answer (score 5):

You can set the `SO_KEEPALIVE` socket option which, for TCP, sends periodic keepalive messages, and may help detect this condition. If this is detected, you will be delivered an EOF condition (most likely causing the containing `IO::Async::Stream` to fire `on_read_eof`).

For a better solution you might consider some sort of application-level keepalive message, such as IRC's `PING` command.

Comment: is there a nice way to pass SO_KEEPALIVE directly to IO::Async (Loop)?

Comment: Not directly, but given the socket handle you can just  $sock->setsockopt(SOL_SOCKET, SO_KEEPALIVE, 1);

Comment: The default keepalive interval is two hours. If keep alive fails you will be delivered a 'reset' condition, not an EOS.

Comment: A fair point. You'll have to turn down the interval to something shorter. There are some Linux-specific TCP socket options for that.

Answer (score 3):

The short answer is there is no default way to automatically detect a dropped socket in perl.

Your approach of pinging would probably work pretty well; you could run a continuous thread in the background that sends ping requests and if it doesn't receive a response the main thread can be notified and a reconnect should be issued.

If you want to get messy you can work with select() to detect keep alive messages; however this may require some OS configuration depending upon your platform.

See this thread for more details: http://www.perlmonks.org/?node_id=566568

Comment: As I said above, the `SO_KEEPALIVE` option usually does fairly well at detecting this kind of thing. Furthermore for application-level ping support, `IO::Async` already has such entities as periodic timers which will help with that.

Comment: IO::Async::Timer::Periodic looks like a great way to ping server